# I want to change iPad resources to iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I created an app of target to iPad and now i want to make an universal app and the time for adjusting my iPad app to iPhone would decrease significantly.

I have set of images (more than 200 images) on iPad dimensions and i want to convert that to iPhone dimension with clarity using objective c (Programmically). I won't need to change iPhone dimension manually, add to Xcode. Because size will increase. if there is an answer for this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly look at this other post in [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712329/how-to-resize-the-image-programatically-in-objective-c-in-iphone)

If you want a pixel wise re-sampling [refer here](http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/resize-image-in-ios/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495518/how-to-resize-image-pixel-size-programmatically)

hope that helps.